# Spliting a column into multiple columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working with a column called `FullName` which stores a lengthy value. 
The format is something like

```
'Microsoft.SQL.Server.20XX.DBFile:ABC.edf.com;XXXX_XXX_XXX;master;1;1'
'SQLVersion.DBFile:Hostname;InstanceName;Dummy;Dummy;Dummy'
```

What I want is to split `FullName` into `SQLVersion`, `Hostname` and `InstanceName`.

I have searched a sort of threads about splitting values which separate by a dot or a colon, which is slightly different with my case.

Comment: Storing the values in separate fields avoids the problem. If you own the table, consider doing this instead of storing multiple values in a single column.

Comment: I don't own the table and I can't change the schema of the original table. 

Anyway, I have solved with Giorgi's answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following trick with `cross apply`. I think the code is self explanatory and doesn't need elaboration:

```
create table t(v varchar(200))
insert into t values
('Microsoft.SQL.Server.20XX.DBFile:ABC.edf.com;XXXX_XXX_XXX;master;1;1'),
('SQLVersion.DBFile:Hostname;InstanceName;Dummy;Dummy;Dummy')


select substring(v, 1, c1.i1 - 1) as SqlVersion,
       substring(v, c1.i1 + 1, c2.i2 - c1.i1 - 1) as HostName,
       substring(v, c2.i2 + 1, c3.i3 - c2.i2 - 1) as InstanceName
from t
cross apply(select charindex(':', t.v) as i1 ) c1
cross apply(select charindex(';', t.v, c1.i1 + 1) as i2) c2
cross apply(select charindex(';', t.v, c2.i2 + 1) as i3) c3
```

In case it is not clear. In first cross apply I am selecting index of symbol `:`. In second cross apply I am selecting index of symbol `;` that is after the index of first cross apply. In third the index of symbol `;` that is after the index of second cross apply. In main select I just use those indeces to grab the needed portions of string.

Fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d79b45/16

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment above that separate columns would be preferred, if possible.  However, I believe this parsing logic is doing what you want:

```
declare 
    @test nvarchar(200)
    , @versionStart int
    , @versionLength int
    , @hostStart int
    , @hostLength int
    , @instanceStart int
    , @instanceLength int     

SET @test = 'Microsoft.SQL.Server.20XX.DBFile:ABC.edf.com;XXXX_XXX_XXX;master;1;1' 

SET @versionStart = PATINDEX('%Microsoft.SQL.Server.%', @test) + 21
SET @versionLength = CHARINDEX('.', @test, @versionStart) - @versionStart 
SET @hostStart = PATINDEX('%.DBFile:%', @test) + 8
SET @hostLength = CHARINDEX(';', @test, @hostStart) - @hostStart 
SET @instanceStart = CHARINDEX(';', @test, @hostStart + @hostLength) + 1
SET @instanceLength = CHARINDEX(';', @test, @instanceStart) - @instanceStart 

select 
    SUBSTRING(@test, @versionStart, 4) AS Version
    , SUBSTRING(@test, @hostStart, @hostLength) AS HostName
    , SUBSTRING(@test, @instanceStart, @instanceLength) AS InstanceName
```